# Tkinter checkboxes ticking at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

In this code, when you select one of the other checkboxes, the other one gets selected or deselected synchronised with each other.

For example if you clicked the aud checkbox, the mic checkbox will act as though you clicked it and **both** will toggle.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

#Themes formatted as [background, text, Window background]
theme_dark = ['#1F2140', '#989BCD', '#121426']

audiouse = 0
micuse = 0

aud = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Would you like audio to be used by default?", variable=audiouse)
aud.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=3)


mic = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Would you like microphone to be used by default?", variable=micuse)
mic.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=3)

root.mainloop()
```

When one box is clicked it is supposed to toggle on its own without affecting the other box.
I have tried changing the variables and the names of the variables holding the actual boxes themselves, but nothing helped.

Comment: The `variable=` and similar options of Tkinter widgets *must* be one of the Tkinter var types - `IntVar`, `StringVar`, etc. - regular Python variables simply won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audiouse = 0` will set the variable type as <class 'int'>

In Tkinter, such variable types will not work.

Just setting the variables as Tk variable types will make it work correctly:

```
audiouse = tk.IntVar()
micuse = tk.IntVar()
```

Comment: It stops them from clicking at the same time but when I read the variables, it prints as PY_VAR0

Comment: You need to call `get` method to access the value that the `Tkinter.IntVar` object represents. Like
`print(audiouse.get())`

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

checkbox= Checkbutton(root)
checkbox.pack()
checkbox.toggle() #<========

checkbox.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, your answer is not very clear, can you add an explanation as to how to solves the question?